# Autohotkey soundplay does not work with every wav

Tags: try-catch, autohotkey

I have noticed that SoundPlay does not work with every wav I use. I can play the files normally, but when I use SoundPlay, some of them won't play and throw an error. I tried to get more details about the error but the exception does not show anything.

In the sample code the first file does not play and throws an exception but 'e' is empty. If I comment it out the other two plays without any problem. Any ideas?

```
try
{
    SoundPlay, c:\Alarm Files\La Cucaracha - Intro.wav, Wait ; THIS DOES NOT PLAY
    SoundPlay, c:\Alarm Files\Marimba.wav, Wait ; PLAYS WITH NO ERROR
    SoundPlay, c:\Alarm Files\Train Crossing.wav, Wait ; PLAYS WITH NO ERROR
}
catch e
{
    MsgBox, An exception was thrown!`nDetails: %e%
}
return
```

Comment: Can you try to rename them to something simple like "e.wav" and report back?

Comment: I did try that before, just done it again, same result, error thrown, no exception shown.

Comment: this will be hard to solve if nobody can analyze the wav ile `La Cucaracha - Intro.wav`, for it is located at your computer only. Not that I could :D

Comment: I understand, I just wondered if anyone had the same problem before. Wave files shouldn't be system specific to play. Another question I don't understand, why is the exception empty when it throws the error. If it wouldn't be I could at least dig in deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm)

**Known limitation:** If the WAIT parameter is omitted, the OS might consider the playing file to be "in use" until the script closes or until another file is played (even a nonexistent file).

```
SoundPlay, FILEPATH, Wait
```

As an obscure alternative you could try running the audio via a DLL call.

```
FilePath := "c:\Alarm Files\La Cucaracha - Intro.wav"
DllCall("winmm.dll\PlaySound", AStr, FilePath, uint, 0, uint, 0)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter if Wait is present or not. The code throws an exception for certain WAV files, but I am unable to get more details unfortunately.

Comment: I updated my answer with a DLL call, but I'm pretty sure that'll drop the same error.   If it does drop an error, then you might get a clearer error message in the windows event log.

Comment: Hats off, it plays with DllCall, thanks for the help. Still don't know why it doesn't work with SoundPlay, but this is good enough for me for now.